# How to get auth0 login screen instead of windows form 1st, when auth0 has to be integrated with windomrs forms based application (4.7.2)

Tags: windows, winforms, auth0, .net-4.7.2

We are trying to know how auth0 can be integrated with windows forms based application which is in .NET 4.7.2.

I have downloaded sample code from Auth0 web site. When you run the application, I will see a form. After that I need to select the connection and than login screen from Auth0 would get displayed. Please refer the image below
[image]

What I want is as the application starts, I want Auth0 login screen to get displayed 1st and once crednetials are good, forms should get loaded.

I am not sure, if this is at all possible or not.

I have been checking on internet and tried few things from my end. But no success so far.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.
Best regards,
SP

Answer (score 0):

The sample code provided by Auth0 was modified as follows:-

```
public Form1()
        {
           
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Load += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load); // addition
            
        }

private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0:Domain"];
            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0:ClientId"];
            client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions
            {
                Domain = domain,
                ClientId = clientId,
                // EnableTelemetry = true,

            });
            var extraParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            extraParameters.Add("connection", "ConnectionParam");

            extraParameters.Add("audience", "");



            DisplayResult(await client.LoginAsync());

        }


private void DisplayResult(LoginResult loginResult)
        {
            this.Visible = true;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            this.Show();
            // Display error
            if (loginResult.IsError)
            {
                resultTextBox.Text = loginResult.Error;
                return;
            }
            
            loginButton.Visible = false;
            logoutButton.Visible = true;

            // Display result
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("Tokens");
            sb.AppendLine("------");
            sb.AppendLine($"id_token: {loginResult.IdentityToken}");
            sb.AppendLine($"access_token: {loginResult.AccessToken}");
            sb.AppendLine($"refresh_token: {loginResult.RefreshToken}");
            sb.AppendLine();

            sb.AppendLine("Claims");
            sb.AppendLine("------");
            foreach (var claim in loginResult.User.Claims)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"{claim.Type}: {claim.Value}");
            }
            resultTextBox.Text = sb.ToString();
            this.Focus();
        }

private async void LogoutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BrowserResultType browserResult = await client.LogoutAsync();

            if (browserResult != BrowserResultType.Success)
            {
                resultTextBox.Text = browserResult.ToString();
                return;
            }

            logoutButton.Visible = false;
            loginButton.Visible = true;

            resultTextBox.Text = "";
            audienceTextBox.Text = "";
            connectionNameComboBox.Text = "";

            this.Close();
        }
```

This sorted the issue.